# What is the effect used in the attached image?

Tags: gradient, effects, drop-shadow

Is this a shadow effect or a gradient effect or something else? I need to programatically reproduce this using Canvas, Paint in Android.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is called a 'Gradient with banding'.